# why MUI datepicker not working in production?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using MUI datepicker along with React hook form, I'm using **@mui/lab/AdapterMoment** as date adaptor.

In local environment, datepicker's onChange is working fine. But when it is built and deployed in production, onChange is not working so if I click on a date nothing is happening. I tested react hook and it seems to be working fine. Can anyone help me figure out this issue?

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapter}>
              <Controller
                name="reminderFromDate"
                control={control}
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                }}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                  <div className="reminder_form_err_container remeberFieldInput">
                    <DatePicker
                      className="login_input remeberFieldInput ip-field w-100 "
                      label="Date"
                      mask="___ __ ___, ____"
                      inputFormat={"ddd D MMM, YYYY"}
                      value={value}
                      disablePast
                      readOnly
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                      renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                          {...params}
                          onClick={(e) => setStartDate(true)}
                        />
                      )}
                      open={isStartDate}
                      onClose={() => setStartDate(false)}
                    />
                    {errors.reminderFromDate && (
                      <span className="reminder_text-danger" role="alert">
                        {"This field is required"}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </div>
                )}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Same here. Looking for a solution.

Comment: @S_coderX451 For me it was an issue with the MUI date picker version. Please use "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.51" to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to fix it too. It was that I needed to import DataAdapter before the other date picker components.